# How to use GCS connector in apache spark deployed in GKE?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Spark-standalone deployment on a Google Kubernetes Engine with the Google Cloud Storage connector.
How can i test the connectivity between spark and GCS?

Followed document:
https://cloudywithachanceofbigdata.com/spark-in-the-google-cloud-platform-part-2/

Versions used :
HADOOP_VERSION 2.7.3
SPARK_VERSION 2.4.4
GCS_CONNECTOR_HADOOP 2